# SQLite LIKE alternative for REGEXP, Match Start of Any Word

Tags: android, sqlite

It does not seem possible to use REGEXP in a SQLite query in Android. If it is possible, please point me in the right direction.

Is there a way to use a LIKE condition to query for an expression at the beginning of any word in the result?

Example:

---

**Entries:**
 1. Minimum
 2. Aluminum
 3. Last Minute

**Query:**
"min"

**Desired Result**
(1) Minimum
(3) Last Minute

**NOT**
(2) Aluminum

---

This is basically my current code, which would return (2)Aluminum:

```
public Cursor search(String query) {
    return mDb.query(TABLE, COLUMNS, KEY_NAME +" like ?", new String[] { "%"+query+"%" }, null, null, null);
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's somewhat of a hack, but...

```
foo LIKE 'bar%' OR foo LIKE '% bar%'
```

might work for your needs (finding "bar" at the beginning of a word in "foo"). If you also want punctuation to serve as word delimiters, you'd have to add OR clauses for that as well (hence why it's a hack).

Comment: Hmm, I'm a bit confused on how this is implemented in the query() method and which parameter goes where :P. Is it all part of the 4th argument? What does "foo" represent? I assume "bar" is the query?

Comment: foo is column name in DB table