# SQLite query keeps crashing

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have this query that returns a particular record based on some parameters passed within a form in my application. This is where I get the problem:

```
String[] args={"act_email,act_password"};
Cursor cursor= db.query(DB_TABLE_NAME,new String[]{"email","password"},"email"+" like" + " %?%"+"AND"+" password "+" like" + " %?%",new String[]{"act_email,act_password"},null,null, null);
```

Here is some code that I found online:

```
 Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery("SELECT email,password  FROM users WHERE email LIKE '%' || ? || '%' and  password LIKE '%' || ? || '%'",args);
```

This code does not cause any problems but it does need some optimisation mainly because it always returns an empty value. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489045/sqlite-like-alternative-for-regexp-match-start-of-any-word

Comment: Ok, I actually tried this in my own app and discovered that the text qualifiers appear to be handled automatically, I've updated my answer to reflect my experience and indicates a working solution, please read my answer and accept if this resolves your problem.  This will help others reading this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your args are incorrect as it is missing the quote marks between the two elements... you must have 2 separate strings between the curly brackets. This should read:

```
String[] args= {"act_email","act_password"};
```

**Edit (Start)**

<strike>Secondly you are missing the  `'` text qualifiers in your query selection string, for text fields these should be of the form:</strike>

<strike>field='?'</strike>

SQLite appears to handle the handle the quotes on its own, so all you need to do provide the where clause in the form:

```
field=? [ AND field2=? ... AND fieldn=? ]
```

and then supply the parameters in an args array.  It appears that Androids OpenDatabaseHelper class handles the text qualifiers automatically depending on type.

**Edit (End)**

Please note that parameterized queries in using SQLite on Android in this way do not like `%` wilcards in the query string.  To use wildcards place them in the arg value instead and this will be substituted in during execution. So your args become:

```
String[] args= {"%act_email%","%act_password%"};
```

OR if you want to use variables here:

```
String[] args= {"%" + act_email + "%", "%" + act_password+ "%"};
```

So the full code should look something like this:

```
String[] fields = {"email","password"};
String[] args= {"%" + act_email + "%", "%" + act_password+ "%"};

//do not use like for usr & pwd
String where = "email like ? AND password like ?";

Cursor cursor= db.query(DB_TABLE_NAME, fields , where, args,null, null, null);
```

Although I shoulld point out in the case of email and password you should not use `like`.

Change the where clause to:

```
String where = "email=? AND password =?";//do not use like for usr & pwd
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you concatenate that much?

You have a missing space between your first where-condition and the `AND`.

Use `"email like '%?%' AND password like '%?%'"` as third argument.

Also: Are you sure you want to accept every password-input which is part of the password stored in the database? In this case "e" would be a valid input, even if the password is "thejdsfsdaf2313!!!".

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] args={"act_email,act_password"};
      Cursor cursor= db.query(DB_TABLE_NAME,new String[]{"email","password"},
"email like '%"+args[0]+"%' and password like '%"+args[1]+"%'",args,null,null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this? I have given an example.

```
  Cursor cursor1=db.rawQuery("SELECT taskid,taskname,taskdescription,tasktime,issync,userid,taskdate FROM task WHERE taskname like '%"+strTaskName+"%'", null);
```