# AutoCompleteTextView with SimpleCursorAdapter does not filter

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, simplecursoradapter

In my app, I have a few AutoCompleteTextView widgets that use an ArrayAdapter.

```
private List<String> adapterList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> dropdownAdapter;
dropdownAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), R.layout.simple_dropdown_item, adapterList);
autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(dropdownAdapter);
```

It works beautifully. As I type into the View, I get words-starting-with results in the dropdown.

I want to do this with another AutoCompleteTextView, but this time using a SimpleCursorAdapter.

```
nameSearchCursor = dbHelper.getChecklistTabDataByChecklistId(outingId, checklistId, nameColumn);
NameSearch = root.findViewById(R.id.SearchNames);
String[] nsColumns = new String[]{nameColumn};
int[] nsTo = new int[]{R.id.simpleDropdownItem};
nameSearchCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.simple_dropdown_item,
        nameSearchCursor, nsColumns, nsTo, 0);
NameSearch.setAdapter(nameSearchCursorAdapter);
```

If I start typing in this new View, the dropdown appears and shows the entire list, and nothing changes as I type. No filtering occurs. What do I need to do differently (and perhaps why) to get a CursorAdapter to work with this View that I didn't need to do when using an ArrayAdapter. I have searched this site and read the Developer Docs and there must be something I just don't get. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site allowed me to answer this question: http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/11/android-simpler-autocompletetextview-with-simplecursoradapter/

Here is my completed code:

```
private void setUpNameSearch() {
    // Get AutoCompleteTextView
    nameSearchView = root.findViewById(R.id.SearchNames);
    // Define from/to info
    final String[] nsColumns = new String[]{nameColumn};
    final int[] nsTo = new int[]{R.id.simpleDropdownItem};
    // Create adapter. Cursor set in setFilterQueryProvider() below.
    nameSearchCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.simple_dropdown_item,
            null, nsColumns, nsTo, 0);
    // Set adapter on view.
    nameSearchView.setAdapter(nameSearchCursorAdapter);

    // OnItemClickListener - User selected value from DropDown
    nameSearchView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Get the cursor. Positioned to the corresponding row in the result set.
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            // Get the name selected
            String selectedName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(nameColumn));
            // Do something with this value...
        }
    });

    // Set the CursorToStringconverter, to provide the values for the choices to be displayed
    // in the AutoCompleteTextview.
    nameSearchCursorAdapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
            final String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(nameColumn));
            return name;
        }
    });

    // Set the FilterQueryProvider, to run queries for choices
    nameSearchCursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        @Override
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getMatchingNames(outingId, checklistId, nameColumn,
                    (constraint != null ? constraint.toString() : null));
            return cursor;
        }
    });
}
```

I wanted to duplicate the word-starting-with default functionality of the AutoCompeteTextView using the SQLite Cursor, only to find that REGEXP are not fully supported. So this StackOverflow topic gave me the LIKE workaround. [SQLite LIKE alternative for REGEXP, Match Start of Any Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489045/sqlite-like-alternative-for-regexp-match-start-of-any-word)

I hope this helps others.